# cant display image to card component on reactjs from backend nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i trying to display the uploaded image from the backend (the backend using nodejs, sequlize) and i try to display it to card component (im using reactjs for the frontend) on the backend i made the image entered and saved to the folder name public/img, when im triying to upload it using postman, the image was successfully enterd into the file, here the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az8YI.png)

but when i try to display the image on the frontend, the image doesnt appear, and here the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CoSQ.png)

the error is
GET http://localhost:3000/img/92c4c0be36fa5f1419f938f509df5472.png 404 (Not Found)

here the code of displaying data

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Card, CardGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

class ProdukList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items:[],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
    this.setState({
      id_user: decoded.id_user,
    })
    console.log(decoded.id_user)
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/product/?id_user=${decoded.id_user}`)
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(
            (result)=>{
            this.setState({
                items: result,
                isLoaded: true
            });
        console.log(result)
        },
        (error) =>{
            this.setState((error));
            console.log(error)
        }
        )
    }
    render(){
        console.log(this.state.items)
        var{isLoaded,items}=this.state;
        if(!isLoaded){
            return<div>Loading.......</div>
        }else{
            return(
                <div className="ProdukList">
                    {items && items.length > 0 ? items.map(item =>(
                    <CardGroup>
                             <Card style={{width: '18rem'}} key={item.id_produk}>
                                 <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.image} alt="img"></Card.Img>
                               <Card.Body>
                                   <Card.Title>
                                    {item.Nama_produk}
                                   </Card.Title> 
                                   <Card.Text>
                                       {item.Price}<br/>
                                       {item.Deskripsi}
                                   </Card.Text>
                                   <Card.Footer>
                                    <small className="text-muted">Stock : {item.Jumlah_stock}</small>
                                   </Card.Footer>
                               </Card.Body>  
                             </Card>
                    </CardGroup>
                    )) : 'Kosong'}
                    {console.log(items)}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
export default ProdukList;
```

here the model of database

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const db = require("../database/db")
//const {uploadDir} = require("../upload")
const multer = require("multer");
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
app.use(express.static('public/img'));


const uploadDir = '/img/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:"./public"+uploadDir,
    filename: function (req,file,cb){
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err,raw){
            if (err) return cb (err)

            cb(null, raw.toString('hex')+path.extname(file.originalname))
        })
    }
})
const uploadfile = multer({storage: storage, dest:uploadDir})
module.exports= uploadfile;
module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'produks',
    {
        id_produk:{
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        id_user: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        Nama_toko:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        Nama_Produk:{
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        image:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
          get(){
              const image = this.getDataValue('image');
              return uploadDir+image;
          }
        },
        Deskripsi:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        Price:{
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }, 
        Jumlah_stock:{
            type:Sequelize.INTEGER
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }

)
```

here the code for post the data to database

```
const express=require("express")
const product = express.Router()
// const multer = require("multer");
const uploadfile = require('../upload')
const produk = require('../models/produk')
const {validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const { matchedData, sanitize } = require('express-validator/filter'); //sanitize form params
produk.sync().then(()=>{
    console.log("produk berhasil sync")
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log("produk gagal sync",err)
})
product.post('/addproduk/',[
    uploadfile.single('image')
    ],(req,res)=>{ 
    const errors = validationResult(req);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            return res.status(422).json({errors: errors.mapped()})
        }
    const produkData = {    
        id_user:req.body.id_user,
        Nama_toko:req.body.Nama_toko,
        Nama_Produk:req.body.Nama_Produk,
        image: req.file === undefined ? "": req.file.filename,
        Deskripsi:req.body.Deskripsi,
        Price:req.body.Price,
        Jumlah_stock:req.body.Jumlah_stock
    }
    console.log(produkData)
    if(!produkData){ 
        res.status(400)
        res.json({
            error: 'Bad data'
        })
    }else{
        produk.create(produkData)
            .then(data=>{
                res.send(data)
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                res.json('error: '+err)
            })
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your react project has the same "/public" folder? when you launch your react project for development it launch their own "server" at port 3000, you need share the "public" folder between react and express projects

Comment: or call the image from the same place at server express localhost:4000

Comment: how to call the image folder from the same place at the sever ?

Comment: you are using two projects one for frontend and other for backend? 
 - react-folder
    - ...
    - package.json
 - express-folder
    - package.json
something like that